# React App Proxy Error: Could Not Proxy Request

Tags: reactjs, proxy

I am working on a group project that was deployed on Heroku, but now I need to do further work on it and am trying to get it to run locally again. It is a React app that uses MongoDB. I cloned the repo and did npm install in both the root folder and the client folder. When I enter npm run dev, the page comes up, but the the functionality is not working. When I try to sign in, sign up, or submit photos I get errors:

From the terminal:

```
[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/account/signin from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

From the console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/account/signin 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

I looked at the error log and it seems like the server is refusing to make the connection. I can't figure out what the problem is. The thing that confuses me the most is that my other team member also cloned the repo and claims everything is working for him. It was also functional while deployed on Heroku. Is there a particular setting on my computer that could be causing a problem? My firewall is turned off. In case it is an issue with the code, here is some of it:

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 
'index.html'));
    });
}

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/leafy",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);

require("./routes/api-routes.js")(app);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("App listening on PORT: " + PORT);
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ai-img-recog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "AI-powered image recognition",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"node server.js\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/deasydoesit/ai-img-recog.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "AI",
    "visual analysis",
    "image recognition"
  ],
  "author": "Christina",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/deasydoesit/ai-img-recog/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/deasydoesit/ai-img-recog#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.279.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.4",
    "multer": "^1.3.1",
    "multer-s3": "^2.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "watson-developer-cloud": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

**api-routes.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const multer = require('multer');
const VisualRecognitionV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition/v3');
const db = require('../models');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Initialize Mongo
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/leafy";
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
//---*

// Initiaize Watson Visual Recognition
const visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionV3({
  version: process.env.WATSON_VERSION,
  iam_apikey: process.env.WATSON_APIKEY
});
//---*

// Initialize AWS
aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

let upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: "leafy-me/public",
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            let path = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/leafy-me/public/";
            let newImage = file.fieldname + Date.now() + ".jpg";
            path += newImage;
            cb(null, newImage);
        }
    })
});  
//---*

module.exports = function (app) {

  // Function 
  app.get('/api/user_trees/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.token);
    console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.token));
    db.UserSession.find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.token)}) //req.params.token
        .then(function(session) {
          db.Post.find({user_id: session[0].userId})
            .then(function(trees) {
              console.log("hello");
              res.send(trees);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              return res.json(err);
            });
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            return res.json(err);
          });
    });

  // Route for image upload to AWS, Watson processing, etc.
  app.post('/api/image/image-upload/:token', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res, next) {

      let token = req.params.token; 
      let user_id = '';
      db.UserSession.find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.token)})
        .then(function(res) {
          console.log(res);
          user_id = res[0].userId;
          console.log(res[0].userId);
        })
      // Set up Watson parameters

      let image_url =  req.file.location;
      const classifier_ids = ["trees_447821576"];
      const threshold = 0.6;

      let params = {
          url: image_url,
          classifier_ids: classifier_ids,
          threshold: threshold
      };
      //---*

      visualRecognition.classify(params, function(err, response) { // Watson request
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          else //get Watson results back
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
            let trees = response.images[0].classifiers[0].classes; // Access Watson returned tree types
            if (trees.length === 0) { // If there are no tree types, respond client that the image isn't recognized
              res.send("Image not recognized");
            } else if (trees.length === 1) { // If there is one tree type, make a database entry and return tree data to client
            // Mongo storage
              let result = {};
              result.path = image_url;
              result.name = trees[0].class;
              console.log(user_id);
              db.Tree.find({name: result.name})
                  .then(function(tree) {
                      result.user_id = user_id;
                      result.sciName = tree[0].sciName;
                      result.range = tree[0].range;
                      db.Post.create(result)
                          .then(function(dbPost) {
                              console.log(dbPost)
                              res.send(dbPost);
                          })
                          .catch(function(err) {
                              return res.json(err);
                          });
                  })
            //---*
              } else { // If there are more than one tree types identified, ask client for help.
                  res.send("Please pick one of these images");
              }
      });
  });

  // --------------sign up------------------------------------------------------------
  app.post('/api/account/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const {
      username,
      password
    } = body;

    if (!username) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "Username required."
      });
    }

    if (!password) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "Password required."
      });
    }

    db.User.find({
      username: username
    }, (err, previousUsers) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Error"
        });
      } else if (previousUsers.length > 0) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Username is taken."
        })
      }

      const newUser = new db.User();
      newUser.username = username;
      newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
      newUser.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: "Server error"
          })
        }
        return res.send({
          success: true,
          message: "Sign Up successful!"
        })
      })
    })
  });

  // --------------sign in -----------------------------------------------------------
  app.post('/api/account/signin', (req, res, next) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const {
      username,
      password
    } = body;

    if (!username) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "Username required."
      });
    }

    if (!password) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "Password required."
      });
    }

    db.User.find({
      username: username
    }, (err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Server Error"
        });
      }
      if (users.length != 1) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Invalid"
        })
      }

      const user = users[0];
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Invalid"
        })
      }

      const userSession = new db.UserSession();
      userSession.userId = user._id;
      userSession.save((err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: "Server Error"
          });
        }
        console.log(doc);
        return res.send({
          success: true,
          message: "Sign In successful",
          token: doc._id
        });
      });
    });
  });

  // --------------verify--------------------------------------------------------------
  app.get('/api/account/verify', (req, res, next) => {

    const { query } = req;
    const { token } = query;

    db.UserSession.find({
      _id: token,
      isDeleted: false
    }, (err, sessions) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Server Error"
        })
      }

      if (sessions.length != 1) {
        return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: "Invalid"
        })
      }

      else {
        return res.send({
          success: true,
          message: 'good'
        })
      }
    })
  })

  // ---------------logout-------------------------------------------------------------
  app.get('/api/account/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    const { query } = req;
    const { token } = query;

    db.UserSession.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: token,
      isDeleted: false
    }, {
        $set: { isDeleted: true }
      }, null, (err, sessions) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: "Server Error"
          })
        }

        return res.send({
          success: true,
          message: 'good'
        })
      })
  })
};
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice offered to fix this problem. I've been working on this for several days and can't make it work. I am fairly new to coding -- and completely new to React -- and I'm getting very discouraged.
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the quick responses! After looking through my files I realized I didn't have a .env file, so there were no keys for the Watson api or AWS. I added one and the proxy error went away. But now I'm still having other errors.

In the app, you fill out the sign up form and then it takes you to the sign in page. I add my name and password to the sign up page, but I don't think it is taking in the information. When I try to sign in, my name and/or password is apparently invalid. (The only restrictions on passwords in the model is that it must be 6 characters.) When I try to sign in I get the following in the console:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: 
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data: "{"username":"Christina","password":"password"}"
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: {0: ƒ}0: ƒ 
transformResponse: {0: ƒ}
url: "/api/account/signin"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
data: 
message: "Invalid"
success: false
__proto__: Object
headers: 
connection: "close"
content-length: "37"
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
date: "Tue, 14 Aug 2018 20:03:01 GMT"
etag: "W/"25-GgaVhntYazB/MPzwqX72WRtisKI""
vary: "Accept-Encoding"
x-powered-by: "Express"
. . . 
SignIn.js:68 false
```

Now I'm wondering if this is a problem with the database.

Here is the sign-in page:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import { setInStorage } from '../../utils/storage';
import Input from "../../components/Input";
import API from "../../utils/API";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";

import "./SignIn.css";


class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          token: '',
          signInUser: '',
          signInPass: '',
          signInError: '',
          fireRedirect: false
      }

    this.HandleInputChangeSignInPass = this.HandleInputChangeSignInPass.bind(this);
    this.HandleInputChangeSignInUser = this.HandleInputChangeSignInUser.bind(this);
    this.onSignIn = this.onSignIn.bind(this);
  }

  HandleInputChangeSignInUser(event) {
    this.setState({
      signInUser: event.target.value
    });
  }

  HandleInputChangeSignInPass(event) {
    this.setState({
      signInPass: event.target.value
    });
  }

  onSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {
      signInUser,
      signInPass
    } = this.state

    let siObj = {
      username: signInUser,
      password: signInPass
    }

    API.signIn(siObj)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        if (json.data.success === true) {
          console.log(json.data.token);
          console.log(json.data);
          setInStorage('the_main-app', { token: json.data.token });
          this.setState({
            signInError: json.data.message,
            isLoading: false,
            signInUser: '',
            signInPass: '',
            token: json.data.token
          });
          this.setState({ fireRedirect: true });
        } else {
          console.log(json.data.success);
          this.setState({
            signInError: json.message,
            isLoading: false
          })
          this.setState({ signInError: true });
        }

      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      signInUser,
      signInPass,
      fireRedirect
    } = this.state;
      return (
        <div className="signInPage">
          {/* <Container> */}
            <Header/>
            <form className="signIn-form">
                <h3 className="signin-heading"> Hello </h3>
                <Input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value={signInUser}
                    onChange={this.HandleInputChangeSignInUser}/>
                <Input
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={signInPass}
                    onChange={this.HandleInputChangeSignInPass}/>
                <br />
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="signin" onClick={this.onSignIn}>Sign In</button>
                <br></br>
                  {
                    this.state.signInError ? <p id="error">Invalid Username or Password</p> : <br/>
                  }
            </form>
            {fireRedirect && (
              <Redirect to={'/profile'} />
            )}
            <Footer />

        {/* </Container> */}
      </div>
    );
  }

}


export default SignIn;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed.

**Update:**

Everything is working now! Yay!!!

Comment: Check following things 1. Can check server-side API is running and working fine using postman. 2. run both app separately client side and server side using `node server.js` instead of `npm start` or `npm run dev`. 3. add `"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://localhost:3001",
      "secure": false
    }
  }` in client application package.cofig file

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not sure if your suggestions still apply to my situation (see update above), but I tried them. I tested the signup route on Postman and got this: {
    "success": false,
    "message": "Username required."
}

Comment: When I try using node server.js I get the message "App listening on PORT: 3001" and when I go to localhost 3001 I get "Cannot GET /"

Comment: I added the new proxy to the package.json file in the client folder, the old error message comes back: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: It's working now!!! Thanks!

Comment: sometime the hell also works i don't why but doing this [ a brought down the proxy to the bottom of package.json ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3MUW.jpg) it worked and you you are using make sure you use axios.get('api/collection') instead of axios.get('/api/collection/')

Answer (score 0):

add "proxy": "http://0.0.0.0:3001", in package.json file after 
 "main": "server.js",

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding that proxy, but the same thing happened (although my problem changed, as shown in the above update).

Comment: Everything is functioning now . . . finally!

Comment: @Yirklum what did you do differently to resolve this? would you mind updating your post for future people to know how to resolve it?

Comment: Actually, the main problem was that I didn't have a .env file so the sign in did not work. I added that file (which had the api keys) and it seemed to still not work. Then I emptied out my saved passwords for the site and tried again and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can add `"secure": false` in package.JSON after `"proxy": "http://0.0.0.0:3001"`, for example:

```
 "proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://0.0.0.0:3001",
      "secure": false
    }
  },
```

it works for me

2. you can use [http-proxy-middleware](https://codeburst.io/how-to-setup-nginx-for-react-a504f38f95ed)